# jQuery ul event target - can i find the li that actually is event target?

Tags: javascript, events, target, jquery

```
$("#slider ul").hover(function(){
  //do something
});
```

Is there a way to find out which child (`li`) was actually hovered on to make this function work?

This is a long function that when originally written as `$("#slider ul li")` etc, worked, but only when completely leaving the slider `ul` area. I need it to work when moving from one `li` directly to neighboring `li`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#slider ul").hover(function(evt){ 
   var targetElement = evt.target;
   // do something
});
```

Essentially the [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) allows you to pass in the event.  This event holds the target element that triggered the event.

Comment: @John: But does this give access to the child li element? Looks like OP want the li on which the mouse was hovered.

Comment: As the event is being listened for on the ul, is the target not then the original ul?

Comment: @Cybernate @sydlawrence The original target is the element that was hovered.  The event then works down to the parent and keeps working itself down until it hits the body.  This is what makes jQuery delegate and live events function. Take a look at this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/bRZCn/

Comment: In this solution, is targetElement returning the one specific li that was hovered?

Comment: @Sarah..yes evt.target will report the LI that was hovered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do 2 separate things... one thing on `ul` hover, and then one again on the `li` hover

You should probably split out the event handlers:

```
var slider = $('#slider ul');

slider.hover(function(){ /* do something*/ });
slider.find('li').hover(function(){ /* do something else with $(this) */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

Try this:

```
$("#slider ul").delegate("li", "mouseover", function(e){   
    var el = e.target;
   //do something
});
```

Working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/hpJJz/